# Сдвиг изображения в цикле php

Tags: javascript, php, css

День добрый. Подскажите идею, как можно динамически сдвигать 2-е изображение на Н пикселей относительно 1-го изображения, а 3-е на Н пикселей относительно 2-го..имею такой код

```
                $query = $bds->query("SELECT * FROM awards_playerlist WHERE who='$result[4]'");

                while ($result2 = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
                {

                    $getAwardID = $result2[2];
                    $getType = $result2[5];


                    $qquery = $bds->query("SELECT * FROM awards WHERE id='$getAwardID'");

                    $getArray = mysqli_fetch_array($qquery);                                
                    $getHeader = $getArray['head'];
                    $getDesct = $getArray['desct'];
                    $getIMG = $getArray['img']; 

                    //Изображения. Сейчас они лепятся друг на друга (Кэп)
                    echo '<img src="'.$getIMG.'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-original-title="<b>'.$getHeader.'</b><br><br>',$getDesct,'" style="border-radius: 0px!important;    position: absolute;    left: 65px;    width: 25px;    top: -1px">';   

                }
```

Буду очень признателен ))

Comment: Не задавайте абсолютно позиционирование(чтобы не наезжали друг на друга) А отступы можете регулировать при помощи `padding`.

Comment: В том то и проблема, хочется с абсолютным позиционированием, если это возможно..

Comment: Можно после загрузки страницы при помощи `js` получать координаты картинки от сдвигать следующий элемент относительно предыдущего. Могу сделать пример, но мне кажется это костыль. Скорее всего другие ребята смогут подсказать более оптимальный вариант при помощи `css`.

Answer (score 0):

А нет у $getArray разве какого нибудь index'a

```
echo '<img src="'.$getIMG.'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-original-title="<b>'.$getHeader.'</b><br><br>',$getDesct,'" style="border-radius: 0px!important;    position: absolute;    left:'. 65 * $getArray['index'] . 'px;    width: 25px;    top: -1px">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{width:100px;height:100px}
img.some:not(:first-child){margin-left:-25px}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="some" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRAJa_7prKkNFnsLRZ1gITWwI3F97LOlvLVtSP0Ns3u7Rki5GLT"/>
  <img class="some" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRAJa_7prKkNFnsLRZ1gITWwI3F97LOlvLVtSP0Ns3u7Rki5GLT"/>
  <img class="some" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRAJa_7prKkNFnsLRZ1gITWwI3F97LOlvLVtSP0Ns3u7Rki5GLT"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите..второй и третий двигаются равномерно относительно первого и получается, что 2 и 3 налезают друг на друга..
Вот ссылочка на скрин - https://ibb.co/FJQ7Rx8

Comment: Ничего не понял и по ссылке ничего нет.

Comment: https://ibb.co/TMQB51k - Обвел то, на что обратить внимание нужно было на первой ссылке..иконки маленькие, но суть понятна

Comment: не, не очень понимаю. вам надо, что бы сдвиг был в другом направлении?

Comment: Неет..смотрите, 1 остался на месте. Второй сдвинулся на 25px, как я и указал в вашем примере. Но третий не сдвинулся относительно второго..так понятней, или все равно не очень ? :)
А нужно чтобы 1 остался на месте, второй на 25пх относительно 1го, третий на 25пх относительно 2го

Comment: Так а в ответе как? первый на месте, второй сдвинут влево отноительно первого, третий относительно второго. я поменял -10% на -25px в ответе для наглядности, но принципиально ничего не поменялось.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что для статики выполняется, а вот в случае с этим циклом - третий не хочет двигаться..ладно, посижу подумаю в чем проблема

Comment: Вот буквально только что проверил локально (выводил в цикле) - всё норм, сдвигаюстя все, окромя первой.